# In Need of simple and surely working demo of Registration-Free COM example with WSH (vbscript/javascript)

Tags: c#, dll, vbscript, com, wsh

I have been trying to get Registration-Free COM technology to work with WSH scripting without success. I have read through so many replies to this issue and tried many thing without success. Now I would need help to fix what is not correctly in my code which I provide below with some further info.

Here is the C-com class library (compiled into C_Com_Demo.dll) for testing purposes I created with Visual Studio 2015 with "Make assembly com visible" checked and "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" and "Register for COM interop" unchecked.

C_Com_Demo.dll is in path "C:\tools\com\C_Com_Demo.dll"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace testClass
{
[ComVisible(true)]
public class StringOperations
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public string getValue1(string sParameter)
    {
        switch (sParameter)
        {
              case "a":
                return "A was chosen";

              case "b":
                 return "B was chosen";

              case "c":
                 return "C was chosen";

               default:
                   return "Other";
            }
       }
       public string getValue2()
       {
        return "From VBS String Function";
       }
    }
}
```

Here is the manifest file as simple as it can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Minimalist Manifest -->
  <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
   <file name = "C_Com_Demo.dll">
      <comClass clsid="{9d3e378b-d20e-43bc-a49f-e7e002eee72e}"
      progid = "C_Com_Demo"/>
   </file>
</assembly>
```

New manifest file VERSION:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Minimalist Manifest -->
  <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <file name = "C_Com_Demo.dll"/>
   <clrClass clsid="{9d3e378b-d20e-43bc-a49f-e7e002eee72e}"
   name="C_Com_Demo"/>
  </assembly>
```

"C_Com_Demo.manifest" is also in the same location as dll: "C:\tools\com\C_Com_Demo.manifest"

My OS is Windows 10 (64 bit). Therefore I set Platform target to x64.
.Net Framework is set to 4.

And Here is the WSH/vbscript by which I have tried to call the methods
of the com-object:

```
Set actCtx = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.Windows.ActCtx")
    actCtx.Manifest = "C:\Tools\com\C_Com_demo.manifest"
Set DX = actCtx.CreateObject("testClass.StringOperations")
MsgBox DX.getValue1("a")
```

vbscript locates also in the same path, i.e. "C:\Tools\com\"

If I register the Com-class either via RegAsm.exe or via VS's build option "Register for COM interop" then the WSH/vbscript indeed works but the the desired goal of attaining the com-class via registration free technology is not working yet. The error always comes on the 3th line (Set DX = actCtx.CreateObject("testClass.StringOperations")) and says

> ActiveX-component cannot create the object, Code: 800A01AD.

Can anyone say what I should change in the code above to make it work - for I really am stuck with this?

Comment: If it's COM shouldn't you be using `regsvr32.exe` to register the `progid` in the Registry?

Comment: It dies very quickly because the progid is not correct, it is "testClass.StringOperations", not "C_Com_Demo".   Not the only problem, you must use the `assemblyIdentity` and the `clrClass` element instead of `comClass`.  And in this specific scenario the CLR will have a hard time finding the DLL.  It must either be copied to c:\windows\system32 because wscript.exe is located there (boo) or it must be installed into the GAC.

Comment: I added clrClass instead of comClass but manifest validation did not accept assemblyIdentity element with its minimum requirements, i.e. name attributes . I have updated the manifest file above in accordance with that. I also tried coping dll into c:\windows\system32. This did not yet solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic requirement to make a reg-free manifest pay off is that you can modify the manifest of the client program.  That is a significant obstacle here, the scripting host (c:\windows\system32\wscript.exe in this case) already has a manifest and does not allow you to embed your own or use a .manifest file.

At best you could write a component manifest, it needs to resemble this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity name="ClassLibrary166" version="1.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6e06a399ac99f486" />
    <clrClass 
        clsid = "{9d3e378b-d20e-43bc-a49f-e7e002eee72e}"
        name = "testClass.StringOperations"
        progid = "testClass.StringOperations"
        runtimeVersion = "v4.0.30319">
    </clrClass>
</assembly>
```

Note the use of `clrClass` instead of `comClass`, required for a [ComVisible] .NET class.  Note the `progid`, it was wrong in your original manifest.  And note the `assemblyIdentity`, required to help the CLR find the relevant assembly.  I called it ClassLibrary166 in my test program, adjust as necessary.  And I gave a strong name, use sn.exe -T to see it.

I strongly recommend you give the class the [Guid("9d3e378b-d20e-43bc-a49f-e7e002eee72e")] attribute so you don't have to second-guess the required `clsid`.  Without the attribute it will change when you make any changes to the class, one more failure mode you don't need.  Normally it is a bad idea to use the attribute because it causes DLL Hell but that's what a manifest is supposed to fix.

Note how I intentionally omitted the `file` element.  It cannot work in this specific case, the CLR looks only in two specific places for the DLL in this scenario.  First in looks in the GAC, that's the best place for it.  The reason I gave it a strong name by using the Project > Properties > Signing tab.  But it requires you to install the assembly into the GAC with `gacutil.exe -i` so you still have an install requirement.  Also very little joy when you develop the code, be sure to get it stable before you do this.

The other place it looks is in the directory where the EXE resides.  Unfortunately that is c:\windows\system32, never a great idea to tinker with that directory.  All and all, a manifest just doesn't help that much.

Comment: Thank you Hans for your expertise - I now came to see the pointlessness of my goal for registration free manifest in this scenario. With the information you provide I do not want to proceed in this direction anymore.

Comment: I returned yet to this issue and scenario - because I was able to make the vbscript usage of the class in GAC work very well according to your instructions. Now, however, I would like to know if it is possible to use the class from vbscript/classic asp within IIS-server? Namely I could not make it work right away because the line Set DX = actCtx.CreateObject("testClass.StringOperations") gives an error: 0x80070002 - unknown exception. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: That is FileNotFoundException, I dedicated the last half of the answer to that problem.

Comment: Yes, I see it is basically FileNotFoundException. But, I found that there was also issue related to the platform selection. For I originally built the class with the target platform being x64. So, classic asp / vbscript did not work for that reason, and the same held true naturally in the case of WSH. But with IIS and classic asp there was still one further issue that was in the way. Namely IIS had to be enabled for 32-bit application pool. Here is a guide for that: https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1114/how-to-enable-a-32-bit-application-pool-in-iis-7-dedicated-vps.aspx. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Works, indeed now well in IIS from classic asp. Can anyone now say how to install the dll into the GAC of production server (IIS). In local server I can have install it with the following: 
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe" , """" & ScripPath & """ RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1

where ScriptPath refers to vbs-file with the following code in turn: 

"Set WshOut = WshShell.Exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe /i C:\tools\com\C_Com_Demo.dll")"